# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>

var a = prompt("введите количество уроков");
var b = prompt("введите время урока");
var n = alert(a*b + 10)

if (n => 60){
    alert(n : 60)
}

 </script>
```

ошибка в 9 строчке

Comment: `alert(n : 60)` - это что такое? В кавычки возьмите

Comment: @BOPOH есть подозрение что это деленее  :)

Comment: @Dmitry, че-то об этом не подумал ) Тогда надо `alert(n / 60)` (без кавычек)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что JavaScript не понимает конструкцию `alert(n : 60)`.

Если вы хотите, чтобы это было деление, то надо использовать символ `/`, список всех операций в JavaScript можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp). Т.е. получается, что строчка должна быть такой: `alert(n / 60)`.

Если же вы хотите, чтобы алерт показал вам `n : 60`, то надо взять аргумент функции в кавычки, двойные или одинарные. Т.е. получается, что строчка должна быть такой: `alert('n : 60')` или `alert("n : 60")`.

Других вариантов, что вы хотите у меня нет. Если я ошибаюсь напишите в комментариях, мы постараемся вам помочь.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = prompt("введите количество уроков");
var b = prompt("введите время урока");
var n = a*b + 10;

alert(n)

if (n >= 60){
    alert('n : 60')
}
```